# Why does 'sudo pm-suspend' enable me to shut down this computer and let it wake on lan?

Tags: 16.04, suspend, shutdown, wakeonlan

Asus motherboard **ASUS H97M-PLUS BIOS** power off issue - **Ubuntu MATE 16.04**

I want to wake this computer using wake-on-lan. I set the BIOS to the following:

> Advanced --> APM --> Power On By PCIE --> Enabled
>   Advanced --> USB Configuration --> Intel xHCI Mode --> Smart Auto
>   Advanced --> Platform Misc Config. --> PCI Express Native Power Management --> Enabled

Then when shutting down from **Ubuntu MATE 16.04** (and also from **Ubuntu 12.04** gnome-panel) the computer would pause for *3 seconds* and then reboot. My work-around for several weeks was to push the power button during the reboot grub sequence to reliably power off. A week ago, I used the `sudo pm-suspend` command in MATE and the computer suspended. I tapped the spacebar to wake it up, read an e-mail and then clicked on the shutdown button. It shut down and did not reboot. Issuing `sudo pm-suspend`, `powerwake <IP address>`, ssh into my computer and using `sudo poweroff` also works from another computer. I've got wake-up and shutdown actions that work both locally and remotely. Good.

My question is why does `sudo pm-suspend` enable me to shut down this computer and let it wake on lan? Clicking on the red shut-down button and selecting **suspend** does not substitute for using the `sudo pm-suspend` command in terminal - the computer will reboot subsequently. Does the pm-suspend command put Ubuntu into a different state?

```
Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection (2) I218-V  
    DeviceName:  Onboard LAN
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Ethernet Connection (2) I218-V
    Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx+
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 0
    Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 28
    Region 0: Memory at f7100000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=128K]
    Region 1: Memory at f7138000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Region 2: I/O ports at f040 [size=32]
    Capabilities: [c8] Power Management version 2
        Flags: PMEClk- DSI+ D1- D2- AuxCurrent=0mA PME(D0+,D1-,D2-,D3hot+,D3cold+)
        Status: D0 NoSoftRst- PME-Enable- DSel=0 DScale=1 PME-
    Capabilities: [d0] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
        Address: 00000000fee002d8  Data: 0000
    Capabilities: [e0] PCI Advanced Features
        AFCap: TP+ FLR+
        AFCtrl: FLR-
        AFStatus: TP-
    Kernel driver in use: e1000e
    Kernel modules: e1000e
```